# Fuiste or eras?

Tags: gramática

En Inglés: "You were good last night at the meeting."
Como es la gramática correcta?
(1) Fuiste bien anoche en la reunión.
(2) Eras bien anoche en la reunión.

Google translate gives me:
Estuviste bien anoche en la reunión.

Comment: Google Translate is right. Both of your options are incorrect.

Comment: It's bueno not bien. The verb is not ser; it's estar here.

Comment: @Lambie "Estuviste bueno anoche en la reunión" doesn't sound right to me as native of Spain. Maybe that variant is used in México. Not sure. In Spain it would be "Estuviste bien".

Comment: @RubioRic Si, estuvo bueno [algo; una cosa] an la reunion. Para una persona, estoy de acuerdo, estuviste bien.

Comment: @Lambie "Estuvo bien la fiesta","Fue bien la reunión" en España.

Comment: @RubioRic No: el helado estuvo bueno en la fiesta. O sea, tenia buen gusto. Estaba referiéndome a cosas no personas. ¿ Porque no les lo que escribo con mas cuidado?? Para personas estoy de acuerdo conttigo; para cosas, no.

Comment: @Lambie yo lo intento. A veces eres críptico.  "Estuvo buena la comida en la fiesta" Perfecto. "Estuvo buena la fiesta" Perfecto en México. Cosas. Bueno y buena. ¿Entiendes que tu primer comentario confunda? Breve y críptico. Escribe con cuidado.

Comment: "Fue muy bueno el servicio de la fiesta" "Estuvo muy bien el servicio de la fiesta". Ambas perfectamente válidas e idiomáticas. Ser. Estar. Bien. Bueno. Servicio (la gente que atendía a los invitados o el trabajo de esa gente que es una cosa). No es tan sencillo.

Comment: @RubioRic  Dije: Si, estuvo bueno [**algo; una cosa**] an la reunion. Para una persona, estoy de acuerdo, estuviste bien. – Es bien claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to talk about quality, you have to combine **ser** with **bueno/a** or **malo/a**, and **estar** with **bien/mal**.

"Ser + bien/mal" is a forbidden combination, while "estar bueno/a" could mean other things. For example, you might say something "está bueno" when you enjoy it, or that a girl "está buena" when she's attractive.

In your case, the correct wording is **estuviste bien**. You use "estar bien" instead of "ser bueno" because the action happened once, that doesn't mean he/she is good at every meeting he/she goes. And the verb in *pretérito perfecto* because the meeting finished as it was expected.